# Cannot connect to internet through ethernet

Tags: networking, 13.10, ethernet

When I connect the ethernet to my desktop (13.10), it appears to establish a connection but I cannot access any web pages. If I connect the ethernet to my laptop (12.04.4) it works correctly. I have connected to ethernet on my desktop before, but I have recently relocated and I am trying to get it working with my new living arrangement.

## DESKTOP (13.10)

```
$ uname -a
```

```
Linux jeffrey-desktop 3.11.0-20-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:32:49 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ ifconfig
```

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:60:00:de:4f:bb  
          inet addr:10.212.9.183  Bcast:10.212.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ca60:ff:fede:4fbb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7883 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:841589 (841.5 KB)  TX bytes:240759 (240.7 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7f00000-f7f20000
```

```
$ route -n
```

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.212.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.212.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0
```

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
```

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: c8:60:00:de:4f:bb
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=10.212.9.183 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:52 memory:f7f00000-f7f1ffff memory:f7f39000-f7f39fff ioport:f040(size=32)
```

## LAPTOP (12.04.4)

```
$ uname -a
```

```
Linux jeffrey-Inspiron-3520 3.2.0-61-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:31:50 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ ifconfig
```

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:db:55:84:bc:f0  
          inet addr:10.212.12.5  Bcast:10.212.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e2db:55ff:fe84:bcf0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7035 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2820 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4817604 (4.8 MB)  TX bytes:444154 (444.1 KB)
          Interrupt:41 Base address:0x4000
```

```
$ route -n
```

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.212.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.212.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
```

```
 *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: e0:db:55:84:bc:f0
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=10.212.12.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the new network was blocking the DNS servers that my desktop was trying to use.

/edit

Whenever I tried to `ping google.com` on my desktop I noticed it was hanging instead of complaining about an unknown host. This means that the issue was during DNS lookup.

I started playing around with `dig` to find the issue. `dig google.com` was hanging as expected. `dig @8.8.8.8 google.com` was also hanging, which is odd because Google's DNS is normally very responsive. I decided to take a look at which DNS servers I was using vs the ones DHCP told me to use.

```
$ nm-tool
```

```
Device: eth0  [Ethernet connection 1] ----------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        C8:60:00:DE:4F:BB

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.212.9.183
    Prefix:          16 (255.255.0.0)
    Gateway:         10.212.0.1

    DNS:             208.67.220.220
    DNS:             208.67.222.222
```

This output shows me that the DNS servers that DHCP told me to use were `208.67.220.220` and `208.67.222.222`. However, these were not the DNS servers my desktop was configured to use:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

```
nameserver 209.222.18.222
nameserver 209.222.18.218
```

I use [PIA](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com)'s [linux beta](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/index.php?p=/discussion/1940/pia-vpn-app-linux-beta/p1) and it had changed my resolv.conf to prevent [DNS leaks](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/#dnsleak) which is normally not an issue. However, since PIA's DNS servers are blocked on this new network and I could not connect to the VPN because the ports required for PPTP are blocked on this network, it ended up causing all DNS lookups to fail.

I restored my `/etc/resolv.conf` to its `resolvconf` managed form and restarted the ethernet network to fix the issue.

```
$ sudo ln -sft /etc /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```